# How to write to a ROS-bag in MATLAB?

Tags: ros, matlab, rosbag, rosbag-record

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am new to using ROS at my university. What I would like to do seems simple: I would like to open a ROS bag in MATLAB, (which I can already do thanks to using https://github.com/bcharrow/matlab_rosbag).

After opening a bag, I would like to simply manipulate its contents, and then write/save it to a new ROS bag, in MATLAB.

Is there a way to do this simply? Thank you in advance.

FWIW I have access to MATLAB 2014 and 2015.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222225/how-to-write-to-a-ros-bag-in-matlab?/) by [tyrana](https://answers.ros.org/users/25286/tyrana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you know that the R2015 release comes with ROS support? It's called Robotics System Toolbox and offers ALL kind of functions to work with ROS, including open, handle, edit and save `ros bags`.

In [this link](http://es.mathworks.com/help/robotics/index.html?s_cid=doc_ftr) you can find the documentation for this toolbox.

**EDIT 1**
And in [this link](http://es.mathworks.com/help/robotics/examples/working-with-rosbag-logfiles.html) an example with rosbags.

The thing is, if I've understood you, that you want to give the command to save a rosbag from MATLAB, right? I don't know if you can do that in MATLAB... usually you save the rosbags from ROS and later you manipulate that information with MATLAB. Maybe you can create a node with a service that starts  the recording of a rosbag, and call that service from MATLAB.

---

Originally posted by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) with karma: 258 on 2015-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tyrana](https://answers.ros.org/users/25286/tyrana/) on 2015-12-11**:
Hi, thank you for your answer, but I did not see anything that pertained to writing a ROS bag? Thanks.